# Display objects on a SCNScene according to their distance from the user

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit, arkit

I am creating an app in an AR environment which shows interesting points around the user. I can add and show all created nodes but I don't get the thing on how to manage their display if they are close the the user.

Ideally, I want to show objects within the 5 meters around the user,
how can I perform that ?

Comment: You can set camera’s far value.

Comment: thanks @E.Coms! Is it on each SCNNode objects ?

Comment: moreover, if it has to be set on the user current camera. I'm using this way to get the current camera `sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera`. Is it the good way?... thanks !

Comment: From this arcamera you can use Zfar to get the projection matrix and you can manually render the node if you have an appropriate method.